# iOS and clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, touch

I have this structure

```
<div class="photo">
  <a href=some_url> 
   <img src=.. />
  </a>
</div>
```

on android if I touch the `.photo` it would click on the anchor, but on ios the behavior seems inconsistent (ios 7), sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't, I haven't found where I should touch so it would click yet

Is there a special handling/workaround to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: an img inside an anchor inside a div

Answer (score 0):

YES, the workaround is to put the div inside the anchor!

as you updated your question, my answer is still the same, take the anchor outside of the div!

UPDATE:

let's say you have this:

```
<div id="body">
    <a href="#" id="popup"><img src="something"></a>
    <a href="#" id="remove"><img src="something"></a>
</div>
```

I think you want it to trigger popup when clicked on #body but not when clicked on #remove!

if so this is the jquery code:

```
$('#body').on('tap', function(clickPosition){
    if (!$('#remove').is(clickPosition.target)  && $('#remove').has(clickPosition.target).length === 0){
        //do remove code
        }
    else{
                    // trigger the #popup in here
        }
    };
```

Comment: is there another? I've simplified the question but in reality I have more than the anchor inside the parent div

Comment: let me see if I got it right, you want the anchor to be triggered when you touch the div, right?

Comment: I think not. Div can have more elements than one anchor.

Comment: Basically its a wrapper with an img inside an anchor (so if you click the img it would click) but the other nodes in the wrapper are other anchors for deleting the img for instance)

Comment: for IOS there are some problems with click function try using,     `on('tap',function(){});`